# Problems with installing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, usb-installation

i'm 100% positive this has been asked before. but ive wasted most of my day off and i can't find any straight answers for my problem... I need Unix/Linux on my computer to run some astronomy programs. I have a 1TB HDD and a 150gig, my 1TB has windows and everything on it. i want to install ubuntu on the 150gig so all i have to do is boot from the separate hard drive and everything i do in ubuntu is on that 150 gig. keep everything separate. but every time i try to install it i get problems.

To list a few, I got an ISO i received no information on how to use. i used the application saying i needed to insert a CD. i don't have a cd. i clicked the "i cannot boot from CD" option and spend 30 minutes waiting for it to do something. and installed a trial version. or something. i went to install the full version and it wasn't reading the 150 gig. HD.

I got a bunch of restarts with "cannot find an OS" and had to manually reboot from the 1TB, my computer not reading my USB to install from usb. and a bunch of other stuff

TL;DR I wan't to know how to make an installation USB drive that will let me INSTALL Ubuntu on a second hard-drive i have. Not Run off the USB in a virtual window. which is another problem that i had when trying to get an installation usb

Answer (score 1):

if you have windows installed you need a windows app that can make a bootable usb in order to install linux. so i think that you can use 'Linux Live USB creator' (http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) i usually use it and it works great for me.

after that if you have a UEFI bios you need to allow the legacy mode in there.
all that you have to do is make a bootable usb with this tool, than allow legacy mode in your bios if it is uefi, after that boot from your usb and follow the installation instruction, in there you can chose the drive to use for the linux installation.

if you have to use both windows and linux maybe you need to install grub or something like that, i don't know if ubuntu install it automatically, anyway searching it on google you can find how to install it for shure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are just using the iso file as it is,that does not work, you have to download a special program to create a live USB of ubuntu to be able to install it

[I recommend you read this post about how to create the live USB](http://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/)

finally [here you can find a full how-to create live USB and install Ubuntu dual boot with Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uVcsFhv2Vo)

I am glad you are using Ubuntu, it is great and it really is better that windows, but it is a challange also, there would be things you don't know and really recommend you to search a little more on google or duckduckgo, and forums, to find the answers to your next problems.

There are plenty of tutorials on itsfoss.com, omgubuntu.co.uk and howtogeek.com to help you get started.

Comment: Thank you, last time someone gave me a program to install it put Ubuntu in a virtual window. everything is working, so far. i'm in the desktop area. and i'm trying to figure out how to install the programs my professor sent me. all i got was a large cache of files and idk what to do with them

Comment: What programs did he send you? If they are .debs they are kinda like .exe for windows i also recommend you to install GDebi (you can find it on Ubuntu Software Center) and install your programs with gedbi instead of default ubuntu software center

Comment: Here is where IRAF can be downloaded:

http://iraf.noao.edu/

And here is where DS9 can be downloaded:

http://ds9.si.edu/site/Home.html

Comment: Look before you try that read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo             You will have to compile your program for it to work that link will teach what you need to do

Comment: I compiled it into a .dep file i guess aswell as used it's installation script. it said it was installed. but i cant find it anywhere, i did the "search your computer" thing for it and nothing shows up